# Como insertar caracteres a un elemento de un arreglo?

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Resolviendo un problema tengo q hacer un arbol de * que quede de la forma:

```
[
  '  *  ', 
  ' *** ', 
  '*****'
] 

[
  '     *     ', 
  '    ***    ', 
  '   *****   ', 
  '  *******  ', 
  ' ********* ', 
  '***********'
]
```

mi solucion es esta de abajo.. pero no se como hacer para poner el espaciado de caracteres en blanco que debe tener mi arbol.. el mio lo develve de la forma..

```
[ 
 '*', 
 '***', 
 '*****' 
]
```

```js
function towerBuilder(pisos) {
  
    const caracter = "*";
    let arreglo = [];
    let longitud = 1;
    for(var i=1; i<= pisos; i++){
        arreglo.push(caracter.repeat(longitud))
        longitud+=2
    }
    return arreglo;
}

var a = towerBuilder(3)
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Necesitas agregar los espacios usando el mismo bucle, restandole a la cantidad de pisos.  Algo asi:

```js
function towerBuilder(pisos) {
  
    const caracter = "*";
    const espacio = " ";
    let arreglo = [];
    let longitud = 1;
    for(var i=1; i<= pisos; i++){
        arreglo.push(espacio.repeat(pisos-i) + caracter.repeat(longitud) + espacio.repeat(pisos-i))
        longitud+=2
    }
    return arreglo;
}

var a = towerBuilder(3)
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Gracias @alanfcm no lo habia visto